# IdentityMapLog csv generated by TfsMigrator doesnot show all identities

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-migration, tfs-to-tfs-migration-tool

I'm trying to migrate TFS (2017.3) to VSTS. While following the migration guide, I am at a spot where I can't move forward. 
My IdentityMapLog.csv generated after `Prepare` command only shows 3 identities however my TFS has 4000+ identities as seen from `tfsconfig identities` command (which shows True for Match and Exists both).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems the AD was not synced. Please make sure you meet the Migration Prerequisite:

> 1. Azure Active Directory: **AAD is synchronized with on-premise Active Directory environment**.
> 2. Compliance (if applicable)

Please exactly follow the guide document to do the migration:  [TFS-to-VSTS-Migration_WhitePaper.docx](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/06/TFS-to-VSTS-Migration_WhitePaper.docx)

---

> **Azure Active Directory**
>
> User authentication in Team Foundation Server is handled on-premise by
>   using Active Directory. With Visual Studio VSTS, users are
>   authenticated through an Azure Active Directory tenant which works
>   very similarly to Active Directory on-premise.
>
> **Synchronizing identities and groups with Azure AD Connect**
>
> By synchronizing your on-premise Active Directory with Azure Active
>   Directory, your team members will be able to use the same credentials
>   to authenticate and your VSTS administrators will be able to leverage
>   your Active Directory groups for setting permissions within your VSTS
>   account. To setup the synchronization, you will want to use the Azure
>   AD Connect technology.  The documentation for setting up Azure AD
>   Connect is available at https://aka.ms/AzureADConnect.

---

> **Identity Map**
>
> The identity map is one of the most important configuration files for
>   the TFS Database Import service since it is what maps the on-premise
>   Active Directory identities with a matching Azure Active Directory
>   identity. This is so that each of your team members will automatically
>   have their personal settings, security permissions, and history tied
>   to their Azure Active Directory user account which makes for a
>   positive experience working in Visual Studio VSTS on the first day.